# Statsmodel MN Logit regression finished with exit code -1066598273

Tags: python, statsmodels, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient

I have a large dataframe [870MB,shape=(938050, 31)] that I'm trying to run a Multinominal Logit regression with statsmodels on it.
As I run the row of the regression nothing is happening until I get

> Process finished with exit code -1066598273 (0xC06D007F)

I successfully manage to run on 10k rows but I want to examine to entire df.
What can I do to run this process efficiently?

Thanks for the help!

lines from code:

```
import statsmodels.api as st
import pandas as pd
import os

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path=os.path.join(export_path, f'regression.xlsx'), engine='xlsxwriter')


vars_matrix_df = pd.read_csv(data_path, skipinitialspace=True)
corr_cols = ['sales_vs_service', 'agent_experience', 'minutes_passed_since_shift_started', 'stage_in_conv',
             'current_cust_wait_time', 'prev_cust_line_words', 'total_cust_words_in_conv',
             'agent_total_turns', 'sentiment_score', 'max_sentiment', 'min_sentiment', 'last_sentiment',
             'agent_response_time', 'customer_response_rate', 'is_last_cust_answered',
             'conversation_opening', 'queue_length', 'total_lines_from_rep',
             'agent_number_of_conversations', 'concurrency', 'rep_shift_start_time', 'first_cust_line_num_of_words',
             'queue_wait_time', 'day_of_week', 'time_of_day']

reg_equation = st.formula.mnlogit(f'visitor_was_answered ~C(day_of_week)+C(time_of_day)+{"+".join(corr_cols)} ',
                                  vars_matrix_df).fit()

reg_summary_as_html = vars_summary.tables[0].as_html()
reg_summary_df = (pd.read_html(reg_summary_as_html, header=0, index_col=0)[0]).reset_index()
reg_summary_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='reg_summary_results', index=False)

writer.save()
```

Comment: break it up in pieces eg, formula, model creation, fit, ... and only run those to see where it breaks. This will need a lot of RAM but I don't know if there is much slack in the memory consumption of the current implementation. How many choices does the outcome variable have?

Comment: the row that gets stuck is the reg equation. The outcome is a probability, so continuous between 0 to 1

Comment: The reqression equation has 3 parts: converting data via formula to design matrix, creating the model and fitting the model. Given the information we cannot tell which part breaks down with this size.

Comment: You mean `visitor_was_answered` is continuous and not a categorical variable? That will not work with MNLogit which only works for discrete choices. The model might create a different category level for each value of the continuous variable.

Comment: @Josef thanks again for your help. the Y var is indeed a categorical variable that gets 0 or 1 ( I was wrong here). how can I break down the reg_equation line into 3 parts?